# how can i train a model with different image shapes in a batch

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

i tried to train a model with dynamic input size of images. it works fine for batch_size = 1, but, it throws up an error if the batch size is more than 1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJA4Y.png)

after digging i came to know that numpy only allows images of same shape to pass as batch.

the code goes like this

```
enter code here
def sample_images(data_dir, batch_size):
    # Make a list of all images inside the data directory
    all_images = glob.glob(data_dir)
    # print(all_images)


   images_batch = np.random.choice(all_images, size=batch_size)

   #creating empty arrays for sets of given batch size
   low_resolution_images_set = []
   high_resolution_images_set = []

   for x in range(int(len(all_images)/batch_size)):
       # Choose a random batch of images
       images_batch = np.random.choice(all_images, size=batch_size)
       low_resolution_images = []
       high_resolution_images = []
       for img in images_batch:

           # Get an ndarray of the current image
           img1 = imread(img, mode='RGB')
           frame = cv2.imread(img)
           height, width, channels = frame.shape
           img1 = img1.astype(np.float32)

           low_resolution_shape = (int(height/4), int(width/4), channels)
           high_resolution_shape = (low_resolution_shape[0]*4, low_resolution_shape[1]*4, channels)

           img1_high_resolution = imresize(img1, high_resolution_shape)
           img1_low_resolution = imresize(img1, low_resolution_shape)

           # Do a random flip
           if np.random.random() < 0.5:
               img1_high_resolution = np.fliplr(img1_high_resolution)
               img1_low_resolution = np.fliplr(img1_low_resolution)


           high_resolution_images.append(img1_high_resolution)
           low_resolution_images.append(img1_low_resolution)

       high_resolution_images_set.append(high_resolution_images)
       low_resolution_images_set.append(low_resolution_images)
   return np.array(high_resolution_images_set), np.array(low_resolution_images_set)
enter code here
```

how do i train my architecture in batch sizes?

Comment: Resize all the images to make them same shaped before batch processing. You may use cv2.resize()

Comment: thank you @hafiz031, but the problem is, my training dataset has lot of variations in input size. (for example: i can't resize a 10*10 and a 100*100 image to 50*50, i might risk loosing important details in the images)

Comment: Check if `RaggedTensor`s might be an option for you (although they're not 100% supported everywhere yet), otherwise, image padding might be an option.

Comment: You may need to read more about how the model works, what assumptions it makes, and so on.  That should be in the `keras/trensorflow` docs.  If you understand some of the theory behind machine-learning you'll see why a consistent image size is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

As you replied in my comment saying that you have a variety of images having different resolutions, therefore here is a solution for you. Just choose a desired resolution for training image pre-processing. The following code will resize all images by zooming in or by zooming out as required. Just choose your source image folder and destination image folder. After resizing all the images to the same size you are good to go for further operations.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sat Mar  7 18:54:24 2020

@author: Hafiz
"""

import cv2
import glob
import os
import numpy as np

# choose where you want to save the resized images (here the destination folder will be created in the same place where the code resides).
destination = r'.\destination\/'  

try:                                        # making the destination folder
    if not os.path.exists(destination):
        os.makedirs(destination)
except OSError:
    print ('Error while creating directory')


image_no = 0
resolution = (512, 512) # use your desired resolution

for img_path in glob.glob(r'C:\Users\source/*.jpg'): # insert your input image folder directory here
                                                     # if the folder contains various types of images rather than only .jpg therefore use *.* instead of *.jpg (but make sure the folder contains only images)

    img = cv2.imread(img_path)


    if img is None:  # checking if the read image is not a NoneType
        continue

    img = cv2.resize(img, resolution) # the image will be zoomed in or out depending on the resolution

    cv2.imwrite(destination + 'image_' + str(image_no) + '.jpg', img)

    image_no = image_no + 1
```